# Inserting CSV into the database using the column names in Coldfusion

Tags: csv, coldfusion

I have been seeing lots of example of inserting csv content into the database by using the column's order/position:

```
<cffile action="read" file="C:\foo\bar\test.csv" variable="csvfile">

<cfloop index="index" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#"> 
    <cfquery name="importcsv" datasource="#systemDSN#"> 
         INSERT INTO csvdemo (test1,test2,test3,test4) 
         VALUES 
                  ('#listgetAt('#index#',1, ',')#', 
                   '#listgetAt('#index#',2, ',')#', 
                   '#listgetAt('#index#',3, ',')#', 
                   '#listgetAt('#index#',4)#' 
                  ) 
   </cfquery> 
</cfloop>
```

I can't seem to find examples of inserting by the csv's column name. Anyone can point me in the right direction or provide an example of how to do it or how you have done it?

EDIT: If my csv had the following columns and I only want LastName, UserName and LastAccessed and the order of the columns can variable on the csv:

UserId  UserName    OrgDefinedId    FirstName   MiddleName  LastName    IsActive    Organization    ExternalEmail   SignupDate  FirstLoginDate  Version OrgRoleId   LastAccessed

Comment: Why don’t you convert the CSV to a query first. This seems like quite a good conversion method, because it allows the CSV headers to be parsed: https://gist.github.com/randomweapon/2640432

Comment: I haven’t tested the method in the  link I sent you. If it doesn’t work, I can send you a CSVToQuery method, I created. And I know my version works.

Comment: You can read the file using `<cfhttp>` instead of `<cffile>`.  If you use the `name` attribute, you get a query object.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk RE: cfhttp: This is great. Which version of ACF/Lucee was this feature first introduced?

Comment: I started with ACF 4.5 and it was there then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out:

```
<!--- SET THE RECORD COUNT HERE ----->
<cfset end_of_line = Chr(10)>

<!--- PLACE CONTENT OF YOUR CSV FILE INTO A SINGLE VARIABLE ----->
<cffile action="READ"
file="C:\foo\bar\test.csv" variable="DataFile">

<!----- CLEAN AND TRIM DATA FILE ----->
<cfset clean_data_file = #trim(DataFile)#>

<!--- PUT THE LIST INTO AN ARRAY ----->
<cfset data_line_array = ListToArray(clean_data_file, end_of_line)>

<!--- COUNT THE NUMBER OF ARRAYS ----->
<cfset arraycount = #ArrayLen(data_line_array)#>

<!--- CREATE A 2-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY WHICH WILL HOLD ALL THE VALUES OF THE CSV ----->
<cfset recvalue = ArrayNew(2)>
<cfset recvaluectr = 1>

<cfloop index ="x" from="1" to="#arraycount#">
    <!--- DEFINE THE DELIMITER USED WHICH IS COMMA OR TAB ----->
    <cfset data_element_array = ListToArray(Data_Line_Array[x],',')>
    <cfset elementarraycount = #ArrayLen(Data_Element_Array)#>

    <!--- SET THE FIELDDATA (COLUMN) TO AN ELEMENT IN THE ARRAY ----->

    <!--- FIRST COLUMN ----->
    <cfset tmp_element_1 = '#data_element_array[1]#'>
    <cfset element_1 = '#trim(Replace(tmp_element_1,'"',' ','All'))#'>

    <!--- SECOND COLUMN and so on... ----->
    <cfset tmp_element_2 = '#data_element_array[2]#'>
    <cfset element_2 = '#trim(Replace(tmp_element_2,'"',' ','All'))#'>
</cfloop>

<!---- THEN PUT EVERYTHING IN THE TABLE ----->
<cfloop index='i' from='1' to='#arraycount#'>
        <cfquery name="WriteToTable" datasource="MyDatabase" dbtype="odbc">
            insert into MyTable (
                column1,
                column2
                )
                values (
                '#trim(recvalue[i][1])#',
                '#trim(recvalue[i][2])#'
                )
        </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Let me know if that works. Thanks. :)

Comment: It errored at #trim(recvalue[i][1])#. With this example, I still need to know the order of the column.  I would like to get for example the "UserName" column without really knowing the order of it in the csv.